# automount a network disk in Raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian

I want to automount a samba network share on my Rasberry Pi 3b+.

If I enter:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.100/harddisk  /home/pi/windowshare -o user=root
```

Next to that I need to fill in the password on the prompt. This part works.

However when I want to automount I need to put some syntax under FSTAB.
I have tried and tried but every time when I reboot the system I don't see anything on the desktop appearing.

Can somebody tell me the exact line end instructions to make it work?
I have very little knowledge from this OS.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely the password part that is complicating things. Try adding something like this to your `fstab`:

```
///192.168.0.100/harddisk /home/pi/windowshare cifs credentials=/home/pi/.credentials,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

where `/home/pi/.credentials` is a file that should look something like this:

```
username=root

password=PASSWORD
```

Of course, in all the code above, make sure you replace any file/share names with the names on your system, and replace `PASSWORD` with the password to the network drive (not the password on the raspberry pi).

---

You can check if this works without rebooting your system by running `sudo mount -a` and then checking you `/home/pi/windowshare` folder.